# Promise always resolves to null, despite that a value is returned in async function

Tags: typescript, promise

I have a problem with an `async` function.

In the inner promise `then` callback, the value is correctly set, but after returning this variable, and the promise resolves, the caller always gets a null value!

NB: This is for a discord bot: I try to get the display name of the user using their ID.

Here is the `async` function :

```
export async function getUserInfo(userNameLooking: string, guild: Guild): Promise<UserSettings | null> {

  console.log("Looking for user", userNameLooking);

  userList.forEach(user => {

    console.log("Analyzing user ID", user);

    let thanos = guild.client.users.fetch(user);
    thanos.then(function (result1) {

      console.log("... This ID user name is", result1.username);

      if (result1.username.toLowerCase() == userNameLooking.toLowerCase()) {
        console.log("... Match !");
        console.log(cacheUser[user] );

        return  cacheUser[user] ;
      }
      else {
        console.log("... Not match ...");
      }
    }, function (){console.log("ERROR : Can't find name of ID", user)});
  })

  return null;
}
```

The code that calls the above function:

```
var user;

getUserInfo(args.userName, message.guild).then(function (result1) {
  console.log("Caller Result :", result1); // <--- always null!
  user = result1;

  if (user == null) {
    return message.channel.send("User is unknown");
  }

  const embed = new MessageEmbed();

  embed.setTitle("NAME: " + user.userId);
});
```

And the output in the console:

```
Looking for user totolitoto
Analyzing user ID 752614956918112386
... This ID user name is TotoLitoto
... Match !
{
  _id: 60abd6dada6f9ad06fbfb9eb,
  userId: '752614956918112386',
  userName: 'TotoLitoto',
  userLang: 'en'
}
Caller Result : null
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Your function executes a `forEach` and then performs `return null;`. What else did you expect? It is the single `return` statement it has.

Comment: But there is a return in the foreach ... no ?

Comment: Yes, but that is the (useless) return value for the *callback* function, not for your outer function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function `getUserInfo` has only one `return` statement, and it returns `null`, so there is no way it could return other data for the promise to resolve with.

The problem is that you have your data returned in a `forEach` callback function. But that return value will go into oblivion. Returning data in a `forEach` callback is useless. It is not used for anything.

You'll have to *return* all promise objects, for which you should use `.map`, not `.forEach`. Then wait for all those promises to resolve, using `Promise.all`. Then find the first resolved value among those that is not `undefined`, using `.find`. This is the value you want the `getUserInfo` promise to resolve with: so return that.

Here is how it could work:

```
export async function getUserInfo(userNameLooking: string, guild: Guild): Promise<UserSettings | null> {
    let results = await Promise.all(userList.map(user => {
//                      ^^^^^^^^^^^          ^^^ 
        let thanos = guild.client.users.fetch(user);
        return thanos.then(function (result1) {
//      ^^^^^^ 
            if (result1.username.toLowerCase() == userNameLooking.toLowerCase()) {
                return  cacheUser[user];
            }
        });
    });
    // Find the first non-undefined result, 
    // ... assuming that `catchUser[user]` is a truthy value.
    return results.find(Boolean);
}
```

NB: I removed error handling, so to focus on the question only.

### Short cutting

To avoid awaiting the remaining promises when the one that interests us has already resolved, you could use `Promise.any`:

```
// In this version the function does not really need to be declared `async`:
export function getUserInfo(userNameLooking: string, guild: Guild): Promise<UserSettings | null> {
    return Promise.any(userList.map(user => {
//                 ^^^ 
        let thanos = guild.client.users.fetch(user);
        return thanos.then(function (result1) {
            if (result1.username.toLowerCase() == userNameLooking.toLowerCase()) {
                return  cacheUser[user]; // <-- will resolve the `.any` promise
            }
            // Throwing will avoid resolving the `.any` promise
            //  ... unless this is the last one, and there was no match found
            throw new Error("no match"); 
        });
    }).catch(() => null); // resolve to null when nothing matches
}
```

Comment: I understand, I will learn about the .map function ! Thanks a lot !

Comment: This answer is well-explained but does not short-circuit on finding the first match. See my answer for an alternative approach :D

Comment: Yes, @ThankYou, short-cutting was on my mind too -- depending on the 3rd party API this may give some time gain. I added an alternative short-cutting solution to my answer which does not need `new Promise`.

Comment: Nice adaptation of `Promise.any` but note this solution does swallow other natural errors that may occur in the `fetch`.

Answer (score 0):

Trincot's answer will run the query against all users, but even after the first result is found, it will wait for **all** queries to finish before resolving the result. That is the effect of using `Promise.all` the way it is used in his answer.

What we really want is a function that works like `Array.prototype.find` but accepts an array of promises. It should run the `test` function on each one but `resolve` as soon as the **first** `value` passes the test. If no promised value passes the test, resolve `undefined` -

```js
async function find(promises, test) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    for (const p of promises)
      p.then(value => test(value) && resolve(value), reject)
    Promise.all(promises).then(_ => resolve(undefined))
  })
}
```

It's useful to write `find` as a generic function because it allows `getUserInfo` to focus solely on its specialized concerns. It also enables us to reuse `find` other places where this is needed in your program without having to write complex code -

```js
function getUserInfo(query, guild) {
  return find
    ( userList.map(user => guild.client.users.fetch(user))
    , result =>
        result.username.toLowerCase() == query.toLowerCase()
    )
    .then(user => user && cacheUser[user])
}
```

Let's see `find` in action using a demo program below -

```js
async function find(promises, test) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    for (const p of promises)
      p.then(value => test(value) && resolve(value), reject)
    Promise.all(promises).then(_ => resolve(undefined))
  })
}

const sleep = ms =>
  new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, ms))
  
async function fetch(query) {
  await sleep(Math.random() * 3000)
  return query
}

const queries =
  [ "Alice", "Bob", "Carla", "Dina" ]
  
find(queries.map(fetch), result => result.length > 4)
  .then(console.log, console.error) // "Carla" or "Alice"
  
find(queries.map(fetch), result => result.length > 5)
  .then(console.log, console.error) // undefined
```